# how to change adapter of a viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using a viewpager to display some fragments, now I want to add a button to change the viewpager's content. I try to create some different adapters, and use `viewpager.setAdapter()` to  use different adapter, but the viewpager display same fragment all the time.

So I want to ask how to change viewpager's display.

Comment: can i use a tabhost to achieve this function. is is possible to display different viewpager in different tab, and the viewpager has a fragment in it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to clear out all the fragments in the view pager first with

```
for(int i = 0;i<fragments.size();i++){
    fragmentTransmition.remove(fragments.get(i));
}
fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

even though you clear out the last adapter, the viewpager remembers all of its fragments

Comment: You may also want to add a `.commit();`